# Moving Zen Cart Orders to Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, migrate, zen-cart

I have searched this site and the ZenCart site and have come up with nothing I can use. I want to move orders from Zen Cart to Woocommerce. I have exported everything from Zen and already moved it to Woo, except for the orders. The csv and xml files do not contain the actual order information (with the exception of an order number, which isn't helpful to woo). I can only find one mapping system (Cart2Cart) but it is extremely expensive for over 130k orders.

So, my question is, do you know a better way to migrate this? If not, do you have a solution I've not thought of? If it were just a few hundred or thousand orders, it would be no problem migrating, but this amount of orders is one I'm not familiar with.

I'm well versed in phpmyadmin so I can export etc. Please let me know what other information I can give to you and thank you, in advance, for your help!

Thank you, 
K

Comment: Theres a reason 130K orders aren't cheap to migrate. You could write a script that takes the orders one-by-one and pushes them to the woo database. You gotta figure out both DB-models and do extensive testing.

Comment: If I knew how to write that script, I wouldn't need help. HAHA I found an old bunked code on github that the developer sent me that I'm going to try and modify.

Comment: Start by reading up on how to do SQL in PHP, and comparing the DB models. Make sure you can SELECT one order and for example print_r() it. Then change the data to fit into the other data models.(PHP's associative arrays are pretty good to use here, or full blown objects if you like, else go with seperate variables) Then INSERT it into the other DB (or table) (again, one order at a time). Then add some loop to not do one, but like a small batch of 25, slowly increasing and fixing problems you encounter. Again, theres a reason for it not being cheap.

Comment: LOL! Yes I tried Cart2Cart service and still don't understand why people choose them. I think `Next-Cart` is a great alternative. It's far more customizable and cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress offers some WooCommerce migration plugins that can help you much in this situation.

**Try this one:** https://wordpress.org/plugins/nextcart-woocommerce-migration/

It allows to move orders from ZenCart to WooCommerce for free.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few stores and did a bunch of migrations. I've tried different methods, but an automated way worked best for me, since I do not have much time to do that tech stuff by myself. I would advise you try Cart2Cart - it's my number one assistant. The guys are really great and make everything run smoothly. The price is affordable, so no need to worry about that. You can perform a free demo and make a final decision. Have a great one!

Comment: It looks like a promotion than a solution. Appreciate if we provide code solutions. Rest can go in comments.

Comment: @Jebin Not sure about that. The Question is already mentioning it.